# How to track logout activity when user directly closes the browser

Tags: java, jsp, session, logout

I have jsp based website where I am tracking login time in mysql database.
I am also tracking the logout time in mysql database.
But logout time works only if user goes for logout via proper method i.e by clicking on logout button.
If user directly closes the browser, then I am not able to track the log out time.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Typical approach for this situation is to use `Heart-beat` monitor. Brief idea is: send each particular time period request to server from client code (via `AJAX`). When next request will not arrive you will understand that user has closed his browser.

You can also read about it here: http://softwareas.com/heartbeat-pattern-supporting-library/

Answer (score 0):

What can be your error criteria in time tracking?

If it can very up to 30 minutes then you can do it with `HttpSessionBindingListener`. which will

Else if it very up to 5 mins or less then as suggested above what you can do is making an `ajax` call to a separate servlet which will update last requested time to the database. If you update last request received time in the database then you don't even need to check for the previous request and current request.

`For example`, if you go with second option and I open a page on 12:05 am and keep it open till 12:19 then close my browser then in your database my last request time will be 12:15 AM if you call to your server from client on every 5 minutes bases. his can solve your problem.

Some companies uses some kind of similar way with different login i.e. extracting some data rather then updating something to database to keep session going through out the day even if you just keep your browser open and not even do anything after logging in.